# How to update track URL before request is sent in Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am new to Android development and working on a video streaming app using Exoplayer

I have to stream from `m3u8` source, and it contains additional URL for different quality.

```
/Stream_LOW.m3u8
/Stream_HIGH.m3u8
```

When Exoplayer selects a source based on the bandwidth, for example `Stream_LOW.m3u8` I need to add additional query string the URL before the request to stream started. So far reading through documentation did not help much. Any hints to proceed are highly appreciated

Comment: Do you have the URL Already?

Comment: Parse the file, do a `find` and `replace` and serve it as a local file to `Exoplayer`.  
You may have to add the `basepath` to the links, i.e.: `https://somesite/...`

Comment: this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59114068/9603922) might be useful. the porject uses m3u8 stream url.