# How to make a Video Player using Native Android that have resolution switching ability like we see in YouTube?

Tags: android, video, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to use a video player eg. using ExoPlayer in android app which will support switching of resolution like we see in YouTube.

My API have video files for 480p,720p,1080p. 
I want to give those options in the player and can switch it from the player itself and will play the respective files from URL.

I have seen solutions like track selector etc,but does that work for online files? I have links like :

```
www.example.com/videos/480/demo.mp4
www.example.com/videos/720/demo.mp4
www.example.com/videos/1080/demo.mp4
```

Please suggest if there is any other solutions like API change or any other protocols etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't convert your mp4 file to hls or mpd streaming format with ffmpeg so you can stream it chunk by chunk and the player will select the best resolution based on his algorithm?

Comment: sounds like a good idea,but will I be able to set resolution manually ?

Comment: of course you can, check the documentation:
https://exoplayer.dev/track-selection.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this project, this allows user to select resolution manually via track selection from hls stream encoded by ffmpeg.

https://github.com/namespace7/HLS_Player

To generate hls stream from a video,go through this link
https://superuser.com/a/1302736/1108219